# Event listener throwing "Undefined" error when variable is quite clearly defined

Tags: javascript, html, scope, addeventlistener

Essentially I'm creating a custom video control bar for an html5 video element. Everything works fine except for the seek bar for which I'm using a range input element.

Now for each element in the control bar, I'm assigning it to a variable in a js function which is called upon window load and adding event listeners. Like so:

```
function handleWindowLoad() {
    var video = document.getElementById ("video");
    var playPause = document.getElementById ("playPause");
    var muteUnmute = document.getElementById ("muteUnmute");    
    var fullScreen = document.getElementById ("toggleFullscreen");
    var scrubSlider = document.getElementById ("seekBar");
    playPause.addEventListener ("click", togglePlay);
    muteUnmute.addEventListener("click", toggleMute);
    fullScreen.addEventListener("click", toggleFullscreen);
    scrubSlider.addEventListener("change", scrubVideo);
}
```

All the event handlers work without a hitch.

e.g:

```
function togglePlay() {
if (video.paused) {
    video.play();
    playPause.innerHTML = "Pause";
}
else {
    video.pause();
    playPause.innerHTML = "Play";
}
}
```

works just fine.

However the scrubSlider event handler, `scrubVideo()`:

```
function scrubVideo() {
var scrubTime = video.duration * (scrubSlider.value/100);
video.currentTime = scrubTime;  
}
```

throws a "scrubSlider undefined" error.

The event listener works fine as `scrubVideo(`) is called when expected but outside of the `handleWindowLoad()` function I am unable to access `scrubSlider`. The only ways around this error I've tried are using `document.getElementById` instead of the var or by declaring `scrubSlider` globally.

I find this interesting as the only differences between `scrubSlider` and the rest of the elements is that the element in question is an `<input`> and not a `<button>` and the event being listened for is a "change" instead of a "click".

Is this error a result of some sort of inherent functionality of the HTML element or something way more trivial which I've simply overlooked?

[Here's a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eyhba2sp/)

Comment: Not directed at OP: I am sick of people down-voting questions just because the person asking is a novice making a simple mistake. It's also likely that if someone searched for "how does JavaScript scope work" he'd figure this out, but he wouldn't have known that just from the error it showed him.

Comment: @JonathanG Question titles should not include tags. Please do not edit the tag back in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I see well, you define `scrubSlider` in the `handleWindowLoad` function (which makes it only available in that scope) and you try to access it in `scrubVideo`. To make it work do something like this:

```
var scrubSlider;
function handleWindowLoad() {
    scrubSlider = document.getElementById ("seekBar");
    ...
}
```

EDIT:
Funny thing that I didn't know: apparently you reach the html elements by their `id` in javascript, if you subscribe to the `DOMContentLoaded` event. https://jsfiddle.net/22oqpcLu/1/

So, this is the reason that you don't get undefined while accessing the `video` variable. I guess you could access `scrubSlider` as `seekBar`.

Comment: As I've said, it does indeed work when I declare `scrubSlider` globally. But why do I have to do that? I can access all the other vars outside of `handleWindowLoad()` just fine.

Comment: Maybe in some part of the code you declare those variables globally as well, but from the code I see, I'm pretty sure that you cannot access them outside handleWindowLoad.

Comment: @Chris Imagine this is a world without features of "scope". in a short, one-off calculation function, you write `var x = calculateVelocity();`. Then, in a later function, you declare another variable named x and then because it appears in a loop, you happen to check its value before using it. It would *still* be velocity. Variable scope helps to prevent variable values from appearing in places that are not relevant to the function they were used in.

Comment: @Katana314 OK let me reverse this is then, scrubSlider is declared within handleWindowLoad() and, as expected, is not accessible on a global level. However, video, playPause, muteUnmute and fullScreen are all declared within handleWindowLoad() and accessible from outside. Why is this? I'm assuming it has something to do with them being accessed from event handlers in which case, scrubSlider should be accessible as well.

Comment: @laszlokiss88 That'll explain it! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @Chris Sorry! I did not notice the fact you said about how other variables were accessible. Automatic ID availability is a funny thing - I wouldn't rely on it for production, but it makes test sites easier to write.